# Where do the Android app Crazy Stone (Go playing program) store saved games?

Tags: android

I guess this is a rather specific question a bit outside the programming spectrum of Stack Overflow, but I have been thinking about developing a game parser/viewer for games in sgf (there are a few already, some in Java Midlet, some for Android) and in the format used by Crazy Stone app.

However, when I try to locate the files created by the app, I just can't find them. I have searched thru both the SD-card and the internal memory of the phone without finding the files.

I also tried to google this, but could not find the answer.

The app itself, so there is no mistake, is developed by Unbalance:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.unbalance.android.igoen&hl=en

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The [go] tag is meant for questions regarding the Go programming language, not Go the game.

Comment: In Android every app sits in its sandbox. The saved data will typically be in data/data/<package_name>. You can only access it if your device is rooted. Or the developers of the game provided a mechanism to reach it (I don't think so).

Comment: /data contains nothing since I have configured Android to store files on the SD-card. /mnt/sdcard/data is missing, but there is one /mnt/sdcard/Android/data folder, where most apps have their data. For jp.co.unbalance.android.igoen the only content are the folders files and files/cache.

Answer (score 2):

Mine are in Android>data>jp.co.unbalance.android.gocsdllite>files>game_sgf. They are saved as SGFs.
This is from a Samsung Galaxy S7 by the way.

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't find them before and now I have the answer. Will connect that old phone and start downloading them tomorrow! I have given one upvote, but due to my reputation, I will not show.